# How to rotate a pipe in an arbitrary angle along its axis of length

Tags: modeling, objects, axis

I have a straight pipe that is set in an arbitrary angle and I need to rotate it perfectly around the axis of its length which goes in the center of the pipe.

I cannot use global or local x, y, or z axis, because none of those align with the axis in the center of the pipe.

Also, there are no vertices that I could select and rotate around the axis going through them, because a pipe doesn't have any vertices in its center.

Any idea? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Consider defining the path with a curve and using the geometry panel to give a round bevel

Comment: .... in which case, you can use the curve's Tilt to rotate it around its  length.

Answer (score 2):

A pipe should be radially symmetrical, and Blender provides separate options for orientation and pivot point, so we could select an edge, create a custom orientation, and then use that custom orientation with a median pivot point:

[image]

We'll just r y 62.35 enter, to, for example, rotate in our custom Y axis, about the median point of the cylinder, by 62.35 degrees.

However, keep in mind that there is absolutely nothing preventing you from temporarily creating a vertex, edge, or face for purposes of creating a custom orientation, then deleting or dissolving what you just made.  It doesn't matter if there's a vertex where we need one to be, because we can make one where we want it to be:

[image]

In this case, that shouldn't be necessary; but the absence of geometry shouldn't stop anybody from doing anything, because if Blender can do anything, it can put geometry where you tell it to put it.